# Python - Position of last character in sequence using similar method to one here

Tags: python

```
def PositionLast(x,s):
    position = -1
    for i in s:
        position +=1
        if i == x:
            return position
```

Is what I have so far - just returns the first. Is there a way using similar means to return the last ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do. Can you add some example input/output. Right now it looks like you're just trying to find the length of s-1.

Comment: Are you looking for the last position of a given object in a list?

Comment: >>>PositionLast(2,[3,4,5,6,2,3,2])

Comment: You code contains bugs and bad identation. Fix it before asking a question.

Comment: I am trying to find the last position of a given object in a list - but I want to do it this way rather than using set length like I have seen listed in similar posts.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to return the last position of a character in your string.For that aim you can traverse your string from end to start :

```
def PositionLast(x,s):
    length=len(s)
    position = -1
    for i in s[::-1]:
        position +=1
    if i == x:
        return length-position
```

But as a more pythonic way you can use `enumerate` and a generator expression within `next` function :

```
def PositionLast(x,s):
    return next(i for i,j in enumerate(s)[::-1] if j==x)
```

If you don't want to reverse the string you can use a `deque` object with max length one to preserve the positions, thus at the end it will preserver the last index :

```
from dollections import deque
def PositionLast(x,s,d=deque(maxlen=1)):
    position = -1
    for i in s:
        position +=1
    if i == x:
        d.append(position)
    return d.pop()
```

Comment: Yeah that works but I want it in a similar way to what I have here ideally - So my way will return the position of the first instance of the object, I need a similar way to return the last instance.

Comment: @user5390224 The first suggestion is based on your algorithm!

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me or this looks like a CS assignment?

Anyway, one way is to iterate through the string in inverse order and use your code:

```
def PositionLast(x,s):
    position = -1
    for i in reversed(s):
        position +=1
    if i == x
        return position
```

There are of course many other ways to do this, and if this is really an assignment you should work a bit on it and figure them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
def PositionLast(x,s):
  return len(x) - x[::-1].index(s) - 1
```

which basically reverses the array, looks for the first index, then finds the position in the original list.